# How to Fill Sierpinski Triangle

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having difficulties figuring out how to fill the sierpinski triangle so that it looks like this:

[image]

I am unsure of how to "fill" the triangles because when I do *fill = 'green*' in the code: `self.canvas.create_line(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1], p3[0], p3[1], p1[0], p1[1], tags = 'line')` only the lines are green because its not a shape, thus how can I get it to fill? If someone could guide me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

```py
    self.label = tkinter.Label(self.frame1, text = 'Enter an order: ')
        #Convert string to integer
    self.order = tkinter.StringVar()
    #Text variable needs to be string
    self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self.frame1, textvariable = self.order, \
            justify = 'right')

    self.button = tkinter.Button(self.frame1, \
            text = 'Display Sierpinski Triangle', \
            command = self.display)

    self.label.pack(side = 'left')
    self.entry.pack(side = 'left')
    self.button.pack(side = 'left')

    self.main_window.mainloop()

def display(self):
    self.canvas.delete('line')
    p1 = [self.width/2, 10]
    p2 = [10, self.height - 10]
    p3 = [self.width - 10, self.height - 10]
    #Convert self.order from string to integer
    self.displayTriangle(int(self.order.get()), p1, p2, p3)

def displayTriangle(self, order, p1, p2, p3):
    if order == 0: #Base Case
        self.canvas.create_line(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1], p3[0], p3[1], \
                p1[0], p1[1], tags = 'line')
    else:          #General Case
        p12 = self.midpoint(p1, p2)
        p23 = self.midpoint(p2, p3)
        p31 = self.midpoint(p3, p1)

        self.displayTriangle(order - 1, p1, p12, p31)
        self.displayTriangle(order - 1, p12, p2, p23)
        self.displayTriangle(order - 1, p31, p23, p3)

def midpoint(self, p1, p2):
    p = [0, 0]
    p[0] = (p1[0] + p2[0])/ 2
    p[1] = (p1[1] + p2[1])/ 2
    return p
```

Comment: You never use `fill` in the code.

Comment: going by memory (and not looking at the code) you don't have to fill because the lines will fill in enough. No part of this shape is ever actually solid. Although my comment may not apply, looking at the "order" parameter. Also not a [mcve]

Comment: [create_polygon](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_polygon-method) ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `create_polygon` for creating a triangle. Just pass the co-ordinates like the example below.

```
c=Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
c.pack()

c.create_polygon((150, 0, 0, 150, 300, 150),fill='green')
```

Output:

[image]